# PG missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I use `acts_as_taggabe` gem 
My News model

```
has_many :taggings
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
```

There's this scope  :
`scope :tag, -> (tag_name) { joins(:tags).where('tag.name = ?', tag_name)}`

Which results in the current error:
`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "tag"`

Generating this SQL:
`SELECT "news".* FROM "news" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "taggings"."news_id" = "news"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE (tag.name = 'lorem')):`

What's the reason? How do I fix the scope?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name is 'tags' not 'tag'.

```
scope :tag, -> (tag_name) { joins(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', tag_name)}
```

Comment: oh god! that was obvious
Thanks!!